# What is the best way to use void pointer for returning multiple type variables in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, void-pointers

I've got base class like that:

```
class Test {
public:
    virtual void* getValue () {}
};
```

And then I want to create a couple of derived classes that implements getValue method (they will return different type variables after converting their addresses to void*):

```
class TestA : public Test {
private:
    int value;

public:
    TestA (int value) : value(value) {}

    void* getValue () {
        int* result = new int;
        *result = value;
        return (void*) result;
    }
};
```

In this case I'm creating variable to be returned with "new", so I'll have to delete it after using the method:

```
    TestA testA(5);

    int* toDelete = (int*) testA.getValue();
    int someLocalVariable = *toDelete;
    delete toDelete;
```

The second way that I've thought about is to create a copy of class member which value I'd like to return and using it only for getValue() method:

```
class TestB : public Test {
private:
    double valToRet;
    double value;

public:
    TestB (double value) : value(value) {}

    void* getValue () {
        valToRet = value;
        return (void*) &valToRet;
    }
};
```

Usage of getValue() method is now simpler, but in that case I will have more memory occupied whenever I'm using this class:

```
    TestB testB(3);

    double someOtherLocalVariable = *((double*)testB.getValue());
```

Is there any better way to implement getValue() method?
I always know what the type will be, so don't worry about that.

Comment: _"Is there any better way to implement getValue() method? "_ Wrap it into a template.

Comment: Why do you need a function that returns unrelated types?

Comment: If a function is expected to return values different types (which have no common base class) the design of the type system could be reconsidered.

Comment: If the results are really "derived classes" it is better to define base class and return pointer to this base class. It will be compatible with all derived classes.

Comment: If you always know what the type will be then can't you just call a relevantly typed function. `getInteger();` or `getDouble()`?

Comment: There is no way to use any kind of void* in a well designed software. If it looks that you *need* this: Think again until this problem is gone away. It is not a problem of how to use a void pointer it is simply a hint to terrible design.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has mentioned variants, such as [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Comment: @Galik: that's a simple solution, but I'll end up with many similar functions and I would have to add new ones in base class whenever I'll need to return another type.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Okay, now I have another problem: [I'd like to store my object's addresses in a vector of base class pointers](http://pastebin.com/Wi0kG9pL) and then use getValue() method to receive value of object with given ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap the `Test` class in a template.

```
template <typename T>
class Test {
public:
    virtual T* getValue () =0;
};

class TestA : public Test<int>
{
public:
    virtual int* getValue () { return new int(3); }
};

class TestB : public Test<float>
{
public:
    virtual float* getValue() { return new float(3.2); } 
};
```

Comment: In this case I think you can remove the news and pointers as well.

Comment: @TartanLlama: Thank you for that answer, but now I have another problem: [I'd like to store my object's addresses in a vector of base class pointers](http://pastebin.com/Wi0kG9pL) and then use getValue() method to receive value of object with given ID.